SQL query to update duplicate data
I had a bug in my code which created a lot of new users with the same email (id was the PK), and this caused my Usage table to save data of the new ID that was created.
User table:
user_id     |    email
------------+------------
A           | a@gmail.com
B           | a@gmail.com
C           | a@gmail.com
a@gamil.com | a@gmail.com

Usage table:
id | user_id     |  usage_time
---+-------------+------------------
1  | A           | 10
2  | B           | 444
3  | C           | 4657
4  | a@gmail.com | 6334
 

I need to write a script to remove the extra users in the User table and only keep the user that has the email in the user_id.
And then update the Usage table to change the user_id to the email that's associated with it.

Side-note: mixed-case identifiers are discouraged in Postgres because they are either quietly folded to lowercase or need double-quoting all the time. Reserved keywords are also discouraged, because they require double-quoting regardless of the case vairant. User is both a keyword and a mixed-case identifier.

I'd do it in reverse: demo at db<>fiddle

Lift the foreign key constraint, if you have one.
alter table usage drop constraint fk_user_id;


Based on the user_id's in Usage, replace them with the corresponding email.
update usage 
set user_id="user".email
from "user"
where usage.user_id="user".user_id;


From User, remove all rows where user_id is absent from Usage. Since you just replaced those with the emails, only those with the email in user_id will remain.
delete from "user" 
where user_id not in (select user_id 
                      from usage);


Re-add the constraint.
alter table usage add constraint fk_user_id 
   foreign key(user_id) references "user"(user_id);



User table, afterwards:



user_id
email




a@gmail.com
a@gmail.com



Usage table:



id
user_id
usage_time




1
a@gmail.com
10


2
a@gmail.com
444


3
a@gmail.com
4657


4
a@gmail.com
6334



